# How do I insert datetime as just hh:mm:ss?

Tags: sql

I'm trying to insert a time into at table.

"playTime" is the datetime value. I don't need the actual days for it.

Insert playTime values ('00:05:15:00') but it's giving me an error.

How can I solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: SELECT CAST(GetDate() AS TIME) - check this, you will understand what format it should be.

Comment: Are we to assume [tag:sql-server]? If so, please add that tag. If not, please add the *appropriate* tag for your database system. Also "giving me an error" is *not* helpful information to include in your question. If you're getting an error, tell us *the actual error message*.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `time` field instead of a `datetime` field.  Or insert it with a date then ignore the date when you select it back out.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just insert time value into a datetime field. You definitely need to have datetime appended. If you are sure the entries to the field have to be of time, change the data type. If not append a default date (say 1900-01-01) and then insert it.

```
insert playTime values('1900-01-01 05:15:00')
```